# Random password generation in C

Tags: c

I have simple code for random password generator in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
char *create_pass(int);
void encrypt(char password[],int key);
void decrypt(char password[],int key);

int main(void)
{
    /* Length of the password */
    int length;
    int num;
    int temp;
    char password[10];
    srand((unsigned int) time(0));

    printf("\n Enter the length of password : ");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    strcpy(password,create_pass(length));
    printf("\n Password Generated  :- %s",password);

    encrypt(password,0xFACA);
    printf("\n Password Encryption  :- %s",password);

    decrypt(password,0xFACA);
    printf("\n Password dencryption  :- %s",password);

    getch();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *create_pass(int length)
{
    char randomString[10];
    int i,length_1;

    length_1=length/2;
    for(i=0;i<length_1;i++)
    {
        randomString[i]=(rand() % 25+ 65);
        srand(rand());
    }
    for(;i<length;i++)
    {
        randomString[i]=(rand() % 9+ 48);
        srand(rand());
    }
    randomString[i] = '\0';
    return randomString;
} 


void encrypt(char password[],int key)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(password);++i)
    {
        password[i] = password[i] - key;
    }
}

void decrypt(char password[],int key)
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(password);++i)
    {
        password[i] = password[i] + key;
    }
}
```

I want to generate password where half the length is alphabets and remaining are numbers.
For example : if I give 8 character then, 4 alphabets and 4 numbers.
After that i want to encrypt it and again decrypt the same.

So i need some strong encryption and decryption logic and also i want optimized code.

Comment: That password generation rule is not particularly strong. If you know that half the characters are digits, that reduces the number of possible combinations quite a lot.

Comment: `% 25` --> `% 26` and `% 9` --> `% 10`

Comment: Don't call `srand` in a loop. It only needs to be called once.

Comment: ok @lan........

Comment: `return randomString;` You return address invalid in outside function scope.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : Actually i was just returning the base address of randomString.

Comment: Yup, it is valid only inside the function. Also Depending on the value of `key`, functions(`strlen`, `%s` etc.) expecting CString will not work as expected.

Comment: For the encryption/decryption part, you may want to use a ready-made library, for example [cryptlib](http://www.cryptlib.com/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to make a random "password generator" in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681149/trying-to-make-a-random-password-generator-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning address of a local variable is a problem (since it exists only during the execution of the subroutine if not declared as static and the value will be undefined once you go out of scope), consider just passing a buffer to be filled by the function.

```
void create_pass( char* randomString, size_t length )
{
    sizet_t i = 0;

    srand(rand());
    strcpy(randomString,"");

    for( i = 0; i < (length/2); i++ )
    {
        *(randomString + i) = ( rand() % 25 + 65 );
    }
    for( ; i < length; i++ )
    {
        *(randomString + i) = ( rand() % 9 + 48 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Return the obtained array

```
void passWord(char password[],int alphabets=0,int numbers=0)
{
    int x=0;


     random_device rseed;
     mt19937 rgen(rseed()); 


for(int i=0;i<alphabets;i++)
{
    uniform_int_distribution<char> idist(65,90); // Capital Alphabets
    password[x++]=idist(rgen);

}

for(int i=0;i<numbers;i++)
{
   uniform_int_distribution<numbers> idist(48,57); // Numeric Values
   password[x++]=idist(rgen);

}
   password[x]='\0';

  }
```